# Wicket Page cahing in DefaultPageStore

Tags: caching, wicket, wicket-6

Recently I've overridden Wicket's **DefaultPageStore** methods **serializePage** and **deserializePage** and enhanced them with logging to track time spent in them.

I discovered that **deserializePage** is never called because the actual page is always retrieved from the **SessionEntry#sessionCache**.

I suspect this is due to my page setting **setVersionPagesByDefault(false)** which creates the situation where there is only current version of a page which is serialized in the **SessionEntry** and then (needlessly) in the **DefaultPageStore** from where it's never deserialized.

If this suspicion is correct, I'm then able to make method **serializePage** a no-op a and skip serialization, which currently takes 3 or 7 seconds (DeflatedJavaSerializer) for page X.

I did not detect any side-effects so far, so my question is: ***is this safe? And if not, then why?***

I'm considering this only as temporary solution until I'm able to move the data from the page to proper cache.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is some info on page versioning: http://wicket.apache.org/guide/guide/versioningCaching.html

If you do not need support for back button, you can disable page versioning - it has not side effects, assuming that your pages handle back button correctly. Jumping back to the page that has no state can create page without initial parameters. Like for example: you jump from page A to B and provide some arguments to B. Now user is on page C and clicks back button. This will result in redirect to page B, but no arguments will be passed this time. If you would use page versioning, wicket would only deserialize page B and execute rendering again.

Here is also one possibility to disable page store:
http://maciej-miklas.blogspot.de/2013/09/wicket-6-disable-page-serialization.html

Comment: Hi, I read the page before but couldn't confirm my scenario. Officially our project doesn't support back button, thus page versioning is disabled. So If I understand you and the guide correctly, It's perfectly OK to use no-op impl. of IPageStore if we don't use page versioning? (Because all the page data is stored in the HttpSession.)

Comment: yes - I'm using it in my project too without any problems: https://github.com/maciejmiklas/cyclop